# Putting Chartist.JS into Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, chartist.js

Quick question, I'm trying to show a simple bar graph using Chartist.JS within a node Template, but I'm having trouble getting the script to run it seems. Do any of you know whats wrong with my code, and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

My Master layout page:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href="../bower_components/chartist/dist/chartist.min.css")
  body
    block content
```

Then the page containing the chartist Code:

```
extends layout

block content

    script(src="../bower_components/chartist/dist/chartist.min.js")
    h1= title
    p Welcome to #{title}

    div(class="ct-chart")
        script.
            new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', {
                labels: ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL'],
                series: [20, 60, 120, 200, 180, 20, 10]
            }, {
                distributeSeries: true
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the code was all fine and dandy, the problem was in my NodeJS code, I wasn't properly routing the stylesheet and script file lookups.